# ! Package pgfkeys Error | compiling a standalone picture as \includestandalone{fig}

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone, pgfkeys

I have two tikz pictures in external files (fig1.tex and fig2.tex):

**fig1.tex**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,class=minimal,border=0pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{plothandlers}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}

\resizebox{18cm}{!}{ 
\begin{tikzpicture}
% \draw[help lines] (-3,-3) grid (10,10);  %%%% help grids line
%  axis
  \draw[rotate=90][->] (-1,0) -- (4,0)node[left] {\Large$\phi$} ;
  \draw[->] (-2,0) -- (7,0) node[above] {\Large$\lambda$};
  \draw(0,0) rectangle (5,2.5); 

%  node point
    \filldraw[color=blue] (0,0) circle (0.1);
    \node [below right]  at (0,0) {\large$E(0,0)$} ;
    \filldraw[color=blue] (5,0) circle (0.1);
    \node [below right]  at (5,0) {\large$E(0,1)$} ;
    \filldraw[color=blue] (0,2.5) circle (0.1);
    \node [below right]  at (0,2.5) {\large$E(1,0)$} ;
    \filldraw[color=blue] (5,2.5) circle (0.1);
    \node [below right]  at (5,2.5) {\large$E(1,1)$} ;

% p and q point
\draw[loosely dashed] (0,1.3) -- (2.1,1.3)  ;
\node [left]  at (0,1.3) {\Large$p$} ;
\draw[loosely dashed]  (2.1,0) -- (2.1,1.3) ;
\node [below] at (2.1,0) {\Large$q$};

% IPP point
\filldraw[color=red] (2,1.2) rectangle (2.2,1.4) ;
\node [right]  at (2.1,1.3) {\large$E(p,q)$} ;



\end{tikzpicture} } % end resizebox
\end{document}
```

- **fig2.tex**

example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{through}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Works
\coordinate (A) at (1,2);
\coordinate (B) at (2,2);
% Works
\node [draw] at (2,2) [circle through={(B)}] {};
\node [draw] at (3,5) [circle through={(B)}] {};
\node [draw] at (A) [circle through={(2,2)}] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

now I am trying include them to my **main.tex** file:

- **main.tex**

xxxx

```
\documentclass[11pt,DIV10,a4paper, titlepage,parskip=half,headings=normal,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,final]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usepackage{standalone}
\begin{document}
% Works
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includestandalone{try}
\caption{Geometry of ionospheric pirce point}\label{fig:figure2}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includestandalone{bivariate_interpolation}
\caption{Geometry of ionospheric pirce point}\label{fig:figure2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and I am using **Makefile** file to compile them:

- **Makefile**

## Generic make file for LaTeX: requires GNU make

```
TEXFILE = _main.tex

.PHONY: dvi ps pdf clean

pdf:    $(TEXFILE:.tex=.pdf)
ps: $(TEXFILE:.tex=.ps)
dvi:    $(TEXFILE:.tex=.dvi)

%.dvi: %.tex
    ( \
    latex $<; \
    latex $<; \
    latex $<; \
    bibtex $(TEXFILE:.tex=.aux); \
    bibtex $(TEXFILE:.tex=.aux); \
    bibtex $(TEXFILE:.tex=.aux); \
    makeglossaries $(TEXFILE:.tex=.acn); \
    latex $<; \
    latex $<; \
    latex $<; \
    )
%.ps: %.dvi
    dvips -q $< -o $(<:.dvi=.ps)

%.pdf: %.ps
    ps2pdf -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress $<

    @rm -f \
    $(TEXFILE:.tex=.aux) \
    $(TEXFILE:.tex=.log) \
    $(TEXFILE:.tex=.idx) \
    $(TEXFILE:.tex=.lof) \
    $(TEXFILE:.tex=.lot) \
    $(TEXFILE:.tex=.nlo) \
    $(TEXFILE:.tex=.out) \
    $(TEXFILE:.tex=.dvi) \
    $(TEXFILE:.tex=.ps) \
    $(TEXFILE:.tex=.nav) \
    $(TEXFILE:.tex=.toc) \
    $(TEXFILE:.tex=.snm) \
    $(TEXFILE:.tex=.bbl) \
    $(TEXFILE:.tex=.blg) \
    $(TEXFILE:.tex=.ilg) \
    $(TEXFILE:.tex=.ind) \
    *~
```

Everything works correctly with **fig1.tex**, but when I am trying to compile it with **fig2. tex** I have an  error:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/circle through'
```

But when I am trying to compile my **fig2.tex** directly from console by using comments:

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "fig2".tex
```

It works !

I don't have any ideas what I am doing wrong.
I am using pgfv2.10 (opensuse)
Can somebody help me?
greetings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`standalone` strips off the preamble of the standalone files. Hence the tikz library `through` will not be available when you compile the second figure. To avoid this, you have to include all packages and libraries (that are used in sub files) in the preamble of main tex file. Putting `\usetikzlibrary{through}` in the preamble of main tex file works.

```
\documentclass[11pt,DIV10,a4paper, titlepage,parskip=half,headings=normal,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,final]{scrreprt}
%\usepackage{pgf}   % this is not needed 
\usepackage{tikz}
%% following lines need to be here also. ------------
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usetikzlibrary{through}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{plothandlers}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%%--------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{fig1.tex}
\documentclass[a4paper,class=minimal,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{plothandlers}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\resizebox{18cm}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
% \draw[help lines] (-3,-3) grid (10,10);  %%%% help grids line
%  axis
  \draw[rotate=90][->] (-1,0) -- (4,0)node[left] {\Large$\phi$} ;
  \draw[->] (-2,0) -- (7,0) node[above] {\Large$\lambda$};
  \draw(0,0) rectangle (5,2.5);

%  node point
    \filldraw[color=blue] (0,0) circle (0.1);
    \node [below right]  at (0,0) {\large$E(0,0)$} ;
    \filldraw[color=blue] (5,0) circle (0.1);
    \node [below right]  at (5,0) {\large$E(0,1)$} ;
    \filldraw[color=blue] (0,2.5) circle (0.1);
    \node [below right]  at (0,2.5) {\large$E(1,0)$} ;
    \filldraw[color=blue] (5,2.5) circle (0.1);
    \node [below right]  at (5,2.5) {\large$E(1,1)$} ;

% p and q point
\draw[loosely dashed] (0,1.3) -- (2.1,1.3)  ;
\node [left]  at (0,1.3) {\Large$p$} ;
\draw[loosely dashed]  (2.1,0) -- (2.1,1.3) ;
\node [below] at (2.1,0) {\Large$q$};

% IPP point
\filldraw[color=red] (2,1.2) rectangle (2.2,1.4) ;
\node [right]  at (2.1,1.3) {\large$E(p,q)$} ;
\end{tikzpicture} } % end resizebox
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}
%
\begin{filecontents*}{fig2.tex}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{through}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Works
\coordinate (A) at (1,2);
\coordinate (B) at (2,2);
% Works
\node [draw] at (2,2) [circle through={(B)}] {};
\node [draw] at (3,5) [circle through={(B)}] {};
\node [draw] at (A) [circle through={(2,2)}] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
% Works
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includestandalone{fig1}
\caption{Geometry of ionospheric pirce point}\label{fig:figure2}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includestandalone{fig2}
\caption{Geometry of ionospheric pirce point}\label{fig:figure2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to somehow tell `standalone` to copy the preamble of the files being included? It is sometimes a hassle to keep copying all the `\usetikzlibrary` commands.

Comment: @DidacBusquets I don't think so. :(

Comment: @DidacBusquets I finally found a solution for this problem: the `standalone` package has an option for exactly this: `\usepackage{standalone}[subpreambles=true]`